# Android DSP and image processing acceleration

Tags: android, performance

I am using IPP for my PC application and Accelerate Framework for iOS app. Now I have to develop something for Android and I need some form of acceleration to boost the performance.

I used project ne10 but the result is not good enough. So is there anything out there I can use that is like Accelerate Framework equivalent for Android?

Thanks,
Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at renderscript

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/evolution-of-renderscript-performance.html

They call it Renderscript but its really OpenCL for Android